# Remove right text (line numbers , ALL) in command line

Tags: command-line, nvim, ruler

[image]

I am using neovim and i want to remove the indicated text (`0,0-1     ALL`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the `ruler` setting. Neovim sets it by default—they’ve tweaked the defaults for many things.

So `:set noruler` should do it.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that `'ruler'` is enabled by default as I was just setting up a shared config for vim and neovim recently.